# I want to Get Date in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format

Tags: php, sql, oracle, date-formatting

I am using oracle database in php coding now i want to get data from oracle in my table local_datatime store in 24-DEC-14 format . and using php program it's display in "2014-12-24 13:31:16"

```
TO_DATE('2014-12-24 13:31:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Is this correct ???

I used this query not working

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       dri.est_driver_id,
       (dri.driver_first_name || ' ' || dri.driver_last_name) driver_name,
       erd.last_tag_status,
       veh.tag,
       rf.tag_id,
       erd.local_datetime,
       rd.reader_id,
       rf.badge_id
FROM   est_driver dri
       JOIN est_vehicle veh ON dri.est_driver_id = veh.est_driver_id
       LEFT JOIN est_rfid_tag rf ON dri.est_rfid_tag_id = rf.est_rfid_tag_id
       LEFT JOIN est_rfid_reader rd
         ON rf.est_rfid_reader_id = rd.est_rfid_reader_id
       LEFT JOIN est_tag_read erd ON rf.tag_id = erd.tag_id
WHERE  dri.est_driver_id = '211'
AND erd.local_datetime = 'TO_DATE('2014-12-24 13:31:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')'
```

Comment: Pretty Unclear can you explain what is your actual need

Comment: please check edited code sir

Comment: Remove single quotes around to_char function. and your code is fine.

Comment: `'TO_DATE('` is a function - so does not need to be quoted.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Display the erd.local_datetime in the `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` format, or convert the string passed into the where clause into a date for comparison purposes? You don't need the single quotes around the outside of the to_date() either. And you need to take account of 24 hours - either use `hh24` instead of `hh`, or put `AM` (or `PM` - either will work) after the `hh:mi:ss` - eg `hh:mi:ss AM`. Your last line should be something like: `AND erd.local_datetime = TO_DATE('2014-12-24 13:31:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: You don't need to quote `TO_DATE` function addition to this `TO_DATE function converts a string to a date.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in my table local_datatime store in 24-DEC-14 format

No. A **DATE** is not stored in the **format** you see the way it is **displayed**. It is stored in `7 bytes` which is **Oracle's proprietary format**.

```
Byte    Description

1       Century value but before storing it add 100 to it
2       Year and 100 is added to it before storing
3       Month
4       Day of the month
5       Hours but add 1 before storing it
6       Minutes but add 1 before storing it
7       Seconds but add 1 before storing it
```

> AND erd.local_datetime = 'TO_DATE('2014-12-24 13:31:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')'

You use **single-quotation marks** around a string which is not the case here. Remove the single quotes. Also, the **time** element seems to be **HH24** format which you have missed.

```
AND erd.local_datetime = TO_DATE('2014-12-24 13:31:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Use **TO_DATE** to convert a string into date, use **TO_CHAR** to display a date in your desired format.